# Why is cuda device count zero?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am writing a simple code where I try to get the device count.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  CUcontext cudaContext;
  int deviceCount = 0;
  CUresult result = cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount);
  std::cout << "device count = " << deviceCount << std::endl;

}
```

> compiled command : g++ test.cpp -lcuda

When I try to get the count of the device I get zero even though I have gpu.

Or is it supposed to be zero?

Comment: do proper error checking.  what does `result` tell you?  Also, every driver API program should start with `cuInit();` before attempting to use any other driver API call.

Comment: after I did cuInit(0); device count came as 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the CUDA [driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html) here.

A driver API code should start with `cuInit(0);`.  If you don't do that, your usage of the driver API will probably return error codes such as initialization error.

You may want to study some CUDA driver API sample codes such as [`vectorAddDrv`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition-driver-api).